# Firebase Test Lab failing to grant permission on GrantPermissionRule

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I'm developing a small set of instrumented tests using JUnit and Espresso to automate the testing process of my activities and fragments, but I'm having some crashes when running them in Firebase Test Lab.

The test suite runs fine on my local emulator/physical device which makes me think that there is some kind of limitation (security restriction) in Test Lab.

From the logs I can see the following error:

```java
androidx.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
...
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:134)
...
```

The code I'm using to grant those permissions is:

```kotlin
@get:Rule
    val permissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    )
```

From the logs (and the Test Lab execution video which shows the application crashing after some time), I'm assuming that granting one of those permissions is my problem.

Is there a list of allowed permissions to request for in Firebase Test Lab? Or any kind of documentation on restricted actions in the application? How could I prevent my application from crashing on this grant permission rule?